# Eclipse tasks is empty

Tags: java, eclipse, todo

I'm using Eclipse (Helios) and I added some tasks in my java classes, using

```
// TODO: blah blah.
```

Near the line counting, I have the little icon that indicates the tasks is recognized but I can't see them in the Tasks view (I tried the tasks view and Task list view they're empty).

However, when I add a Task by right clicking near the line counting and choosing "Add a task", this new one appears in the "Tasks" view correctly!

What am I missing to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check the corresponding task tags defined in preferences: use the Preference page General/Editors/Structured Text Editors/Task Tags, and make sure, the corresponding tag is available.

Then, check the Tasks view content settings: open the view menu (white triangle next to the minimize and maximize icons), and select the option Configure contents. The most important things to check are the selected configurations on the left side and the scope settings on the right side.

EDIT: the Task list view is contributed by Mylyn, and does not use the task tags defined in the source.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried what you said (using Tasks view and not Task list, which is for Mylyn as you said), but I can't still see the tasks. In "configurations", I checked "TODOs", in Scope, I selected "On any element", in "Show results matching:", I selected "Any enabled filter" and then "All enabled filters". Everything else is checked, but still no tasks shown :/

Comment: For some reason, it worked after a few days .. (I HATE THAT ! :p)

Answer (score 7):

For those who are still having this problem, my case was that I was looking for my tasks in the **TASK LIST** view. I just had to open the correct view, i.e., the **TASKS** view. I know the author of the question mentioned that, but I missed it the first time :P

Comment: So did I... Took me a good couple of minutes and your answer to figure it out. Thx.

Answer (score 5):

I tried all of the above and still my TODO's were not appearing on the Task view. Finally I ran Project->Clean and they did appear. Hoorah.

Comment: It was the same for me. 
I check the configuration twice but only after a project clean I was able to see the project's tasks. 
Thanks for your answer, you gained a +1.

Answer (score 4):

Task list is built on project build phase, so if you have any problems that prevent build, for example build path problems, then the task list is not populated.

Check Problems tab for build problems.

Comment: Very good, thank you, now I'll just have to figure out, how to make it build with ignoring the errors, since I'm trying to use eclipse for different code (X++ - Microsoft Dynamics AX), the highlighting looks fine, but the Tasks don't work yet, do you know how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1):

see this, I've meet this problem recently and finally I found it's because that I import the project as maven project, the problem was solved after I run mvn eclipse:eclipse under the project dir and reimport the project as java project, hope this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned the project and they still weren't showing...however, when I went to another tab, and came back, there they were.

Answer (score 0):

On a Maven project Maven/Upddate Project filled up the Tasks window will all the TODO items

Answer (score -1):

same issue but I found this in Juno :
One must have the "make target" view opened, and here the project highlighted.
At this moment, the Tasks panel (not "task list") will show the filtered TODOs for the only project