# Eclipse Mars (Java) : Tasks view not showing my TODO tasks in my code comments

Tags: java, eclipse, todo

I've looked at every question I could find related to this issue and found nothing for Mars specifically (not sure if it matters), but more importantly nothing that resolved this problem for me.

I'm not using AspectJ.

- I've configured the tasks view to show everything and I see tasks from js/html/css files in MY projects but not from .java files.
- I can see a few tasks from java files in other projects, which led me to think it might be a build problem but my project is building.  It has errors (only js/xml), but the build path is fine and Eclipse is building the project.
- I've tried changing the java task tags preference to force a rebuild and still no luck
- I've also tried the markers view and that again showed me some tasks from java files in other projects, but not the main project that I"m interested in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is Eclipse *compiling* the project itself, or by building do you mean kicking off Maven or some other build tool?

Comment: Eclipse is compiling the project.. I've verified the .class files in the output folder and forced full rebuild.

This answer says it won't populate if there are build path problems (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7836647/742281)  I have build path problems, but for other projects.  The project that contains my TODO entries has no build path problems.  Where do I see the output of Eclipse's project\build?

Comment: Does this project depend on any of those?